How would you say the name Shireen Durrani in japanese?
My name is Shireen Durrani and my name is Pakistani.
Would it be 『シリーン・ドゥラニ』? Or 『シリーン・ヅラニ』? Would the last name come first?
I am not very experienced in japanese so please explain

I mean, you're the only one who knows how the pronunciation of your name sounds.  So just match up the sounds (as close as possible) to Japanese.

シリーン・ドゥラニ looks just fine.

(I'm assuming you are looking for how to write your name in Katakana)
In general, unless you have a very uncommon name, someone with the same name is already transcribed to Japanese (or other widely used languages). So you can simply search on the web. Perhaps the easiest would be to search on Wikipedia then go to the version of the language you are after (in this case, Japanese).
This woman's name is transcribed as シーリーン. And searching for Durrani gives this tribe name, which is transcribed to ドゥッラーニー.
As for the order, practically it is your choice. You can use the order you use in your native language and can clarify which is the last/family name if asked. That said, Japanese people tend to think that non-Japanese (or non-Eastern) names are ordered as LastName FamilyName.
